# Importing shapefile from CMEC Zoogeographic Realms and Regions paper, in R

Tags: r, maps, gis, geospatial

I am trying to import a shapefile of 11 biogeographic regions in R. The data containing the shapefile I am interested in are available here (https://macroecology.ku.dk/resources/wallace) under the heading "GIS maps of CMEC zoogeographic realms and regions." Once you download this folder, the data I am interested in are (I believe) in the file labeled "newRealms.shp". I put this file in my working directory.

To try and open this file, I have run the following code:

```
library(sf)
realms <- read_sf("newRealms.shp")
```

However, I get an error that says: "Cannot open [the file pathway\newRealms.shp]; The source could be corrupt or not supported. See `st_drivers()` for a list of supported formats.
In addition: Warning message:
In CPL_read_ogr(dsn, layer, query, as.character(options), quiet,  :
GDAL Error 4: Unable to open [the file pathway\newRealms.shx] or [the file pathway\newRealms.SHX]. Set SHAPE_RESTORE_SHX config option to YES to restore or create it.

I also tried to open the file by just clicking on it under "Files" in RStudio. When I do this, I get a warning that says "File is binary rather than text so cannot be opened by the source editor."

Any suggestions as to how I can open this file? I am new to sf.

EDIT: Adding results of sessionInfo()

R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.utf8
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.utf8

time zone: America/Denver
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] spData_2.3.0    flipPlots_1.3.6 devtools_2.4.5  usethis_2.2.2   maps_3.4.1
[6] sf_1.0-14       janitor_2.2.0   lubridate_1.9.2 forcats_1.0.0   stringr_1.5.0
[11] dplyr_1.1.2     purrr_1.0.2     readr_2.1.4     tidyr_1.3.0     tibble_3.2.1
[16] ggplot2_3.4.3   tidyverse_2.0.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] rstudioapi_0.15.0          jsonlite_1.8.7             magrittr_2.0.3
[4] farver_2.1.1               rmarkdown_2.25             fs_1.6.3
[7] vctrs_0.6.3                memoise_2.0.1              base64enc_0.1-3
[10] htmltools_0.5.6            Formula_1.2-5              KernSmooth_2.23-21
[13] htmlwidgets_1.6.2          plyr_1.8.9                 plotly_4.10.3
[16] cachem_1.0.8               networkD3_0.5.0            flipTime_2.10.0
[19] igraph_1.5.1               mime_0.12                  lifecycle_1.0.3
[22] pkgconfig_2.0.3            Matrix_1.6-1               R6_2.5.1
[25] fastmap_1.1.1              shiny_1.7.5.1              snakecase_0.11.1
[28] digest_0.6.33              colorspace_2.1-0           ps_1.7.5
[31] pkgload_1.3.2.1            Hmisc_5.1-1                labeling_0.4.3
[34] fansi_1.0.4                timechange_0.2.0           rhtmlMetro_1.0.7
[37] httr_1.4.7                 mgcv_1.8-42                compiler_4.3.1
[40] sparkline_2.0              proxy_0.4-27               remotes_2.4.2.1
[43] bit64_4.0.5                withr_2.5.2                htmlTable_2.4.2
[46] backports_1.4.1            flipFormat_1.11.1          DBI_1.1.3
[49] pkgbuild_1.4.2             sessioninfo_1.2.2          classInt_0.4-9
[52] tools_4.3.1                formattable_0.2.2.1        units_0.8-3
[55] foreign_0.8-84             verbs_0.15.8               httpuv_1.6.11
[58] nnet_7.3-19                glue_1.6.2                 flipU_1.5.12
[61] callr_3.7.3                nlme_3.1-162               promises_1.2.1
[64] grid_4.3.1                 checkmate_2.3.0            cluster_2.1.4
[67] generics_0.1.3             gtable_0.3.4               tzdb_0.4.0
[70] class_7.3-22               data.table_1.14.8          hms_1.1.3
[73] sp_2.0-0                   xml2_1.3.5                 utf8_1.2.3
[76] pillar_1.9.0               vroom_1.6.3                later_1.3.1
[79] splines_4.3.1              lattice_0.21-8             bit_4.0.5
[82] flipTransformations_1.14.3 tidyselect_1.2.0           striprtf_0.6.0
[85] miniUI_0.1.1.1             knitr_1.45                 gridExtra_2.3
[88] xfun_0.41                  DT_0.2.10                  stringi_1.7.12
[91] lazyeval_0.2.2             evaluate_0.23              data.tree_1.0.0
[94] cli_3.6.1                  rpart_4.1.19               xtable_1.8-4
[97] munsell_0.5.0              processx_3.8.2             Rcpp_1.0.11
[100] parallel_4.3.1             ellipsis_0.3.2             prettyunits_1.1.1
[103] profvis_0.3.8              urlchecker_1.0.1           viridisLite_0.4.2
[106] scales_1.2.1               e1071_1.7-13               crayon_1.5.2
[109] rlang_1.1.1

Comment: No issues on my machine. `newRealms.shp` is in your working directory? Perhaps the output of `sessionInfo()` helps others solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I re-downloaded and unzipped the folder and it is now working. I'm not sure what changed exactly. I now have my directory referring to the entire unzipped folder rather than just putting the single file of interest in my WD. There do appear to be two similar files in the folder ("newRealms.sph", which appears to be an XML document, and "newRealms" which is an shp file). Perhaps I pulled out the wrong file?